# How do I pull a remote branch in git without conflicts?

Tags: git, pull, git-pull

There is a branch on remote I would like to work on. It is old and I no longer have an old copy of it on my local machine. It is really far behind master. Whenever I attempt to pull it I get conflicts. I just want to create an exact duplicate of the remote branch on my local system. Why would that lead to conflicts?

I tried:

```
git pull origin branch_name:branch_name
```

That created a new branch on my local machine with the right name, but it led to conflicts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b newoldbranch oldoldbranch
```

Comment: I had to specify remote: `git checkout -b branch origin/branch`

Comment: @Francisco, yes, oldoldbranch means full branch specification as it's stored in local repository.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I didn't assume it that way.

Comment: Sorry about that, @Francisco.

Answer (score 5):

`git pull repo branch` is basically shorthand for `git fetch repo branch` and `git merge repo/branch`.  I'm not one to often say RTFM, especially with git, but it is the first line of the [git-pull docs](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html).  "git-pull - Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch".  The implicit merge is causing the conflict.  You just want a `fetch` & `checkout` as Michael said.

Comment: Yeah, it'll do that.  Trust me, its worth the effort.  So much simpler than SVN once you get it.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you simply check it out ?

```
git checkout branch_name
```

?

Comment: This sort of worked, but I had to change it:

git branch branch_name origin/branch_name
git checkout branch_name

Comment: It's not that I mind, but isn't it funny that you accepted this answer, although you had to change it to mine? ;-) git branch + git checkout is equivalent to git checkout -b ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I like to change to another local branch, remove an existing one where I want to pull (for example **task_branch**), and change again:

- `git checkout -` // changing to previous branch, or just `git checkout master`
- `git branch -D task_branch` // remove local branch
- `git fetch` // fetch data from remote
- `git checkout task_branch` // change to the branch with the newest changes

and optionally check if everything is up to date by `git pull`

Answer (score 0):

```
git fetch origin

git pull mybranch origin/mybranch
```